# ITOA function how to fix in 20 line

Tags: c

I'm writing a code for RLE compression, but I have problems with itoa function in 20 line. How I can solve this problem? I am new to C, so I'll be happy if you could me a part of code with changes. T-H-A-N-K Y-O-U! (sorry for repeating but I just can't leave comments) and I will appreciate if you point me the part where I should insert changes!!!!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void StringRLE(char *pointer)    {
    char *rle = new char[strlen(pointer)];
    int i = 0;
    int rleCount = 1;
    char *s = pointer + 1, ch[2] = { 0, 0 };
    while (*pointer != '\0')        {
        if (*pointer == *s)
            rleCount++;
        else{
            _itoa_s(rleCount, rle, 10);
            ch[0] = *pointer;
            strcat(rle, ch);
            puts(rle);
            rleCount = 1;
        }

        pointer++;
        s++;
        i++;
    }
}
```

**ERRORS:**

```
Error C2660 Function Does Not Take 3 Arguments ;No instance of overload function
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, MSDN functions... well, [_itoa_s()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0we9x30h.aspx) takes 4 arguments, and you only gave it three, hence the error saying it doesn't take 3 arguments.

```
errno_t _itoa_s(
   int value,
   char *buffer,
   size_t sizeInCharacters,
   int radix 
);
```

"No instance of overload function" is telling you that there isn't more than 1 `_itoa_s()` function that takes less arguments. Looks like you're missing the `radix` or `sizeInCharacters`:

> [in] sizeInCharacters
>   Size of the buffer in single-byte characters or wide characters.
>   [in] radix
>   Base of value; which must be in the range 2–36.

Comment: Actually, the 10 looks like it's meant to be the `radix`.  It's the `sizeInCharacters` that's missing.

Comment: @Wyzard - well, to be fair it could be either one of them that's missing... OP never specified base 10, but you are correct that was *probably* the intent. I've updated the answer to cover either case.